# How to On() MIC through Programming in android

Tags: android, audio

I am going to create an app that is Sound Intensity level,in this app I need to ON MIC when my app is running.can I do this

Please help me

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can just "turn on" the microphone and let it sit to gather data without recording. From the little bit I've read, they record for a brief period of time and analyze that data, and repeat.. for as long as you need the app to run. Here are three links where they sound like they're doing something similar to what you want. Hope this helps.

[Android: sample microphone without recording to get live amplitude/level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777060/android-sample-microphone-without-recording-to-get-live-amplitude-level)

[Return amplitude of the mic input when not recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830963/return-amplitude-of-the-mic-input-when-not-recording)

[Android: sample microphone without recording to get live amplitude/level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777060/android-sample-microphone-without-recording-to-get-live-amplitude-level)